# how to use erlang function term_to_json?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erlangweb

I don't know how to use erlang function term_to_json and json_to_term, do I need to install some plugins or  the moudule of those functions are not "erlang"?

Comment: you should take a look at this SQ question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652296/erlang-json-libraries-serialization-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no such function in Erlang. There is Erlang Enhancement Proposal, which describes this:

http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0018.html

but it is not yet part of the language. Fortunately, there is quite a few libraries, that solve the problem. I can recommend:

https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx

It is actively maintained, battle tested and used internally in bigger projects like Chicago Boss.

Answer (score -1):

As @tkowal has said, `term_to_json` and `json_to_term` do not exist in the `erlang` module.

If you are looking for a simple way to encode and decode erlang terms to and from binaries or strings you can use `term_to_binary/1` or `term_to_binary/2`. These two functions will encode erlang terms to binaries, which can be stored or sent over the network, to be later decoded again by erlang.